# How do I return list of queues with emails?

Tags: rest, rt

I need our ticket system Request tracker to search for all queues and return list of them with emails
Is there search query for it?

```
wget -qO- --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'user=xx&pass=xx' "https://127.0.0.1/REST/1.0/search/queue?query="
```

This command gives all name queues but need to add the emails. That’s possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Use this:

```
wget -qO- --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'user=xx&pass=xx' "https://127.0.0.1/REST/1.0/search/queue?query=\&fields=CorrespondAddress,CommentAddress"
```

More information in [RT wiki](https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST).